# Old(ish) application doesn't work in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos

I recently downloaded the Public Beta of macOS Sierra, and everything is working perfectly - except that one application won't launch. macOS draws a large banned / not allowed sign through the icon (see image), and when clicked displays a dialog saying:

> You can’t use this version of the application “Fraise.app” with this version of macOS.

[image]

This is interesting as it was **not** a PowerPC application - I have upgraded from El Captain (where the application worked fine), not some ancient system such as Mac OS X Leopard.

I can't seem to find any information online about such a problem, nor can I understand why it is occurring. OS updates normally do not stop previously working apps from running unless there is a very significant change in architecture - which there is not as far as I'm aware.

So, my question is: why is this happening, and is there anything that I can do to get the app running again?

---

Also, I know it is beta software, and that there are all sorts of bugs / problems / risks involved in running it, which could explain this. The application is not vital to my workflow, nor am I using my main computer to run the beta. I am more just interested in why this is happening then if there is a fix.

Comment: First thing I'd do is ask the developers of 'Fraise'. They might already be aware & know a fix/workaround.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Console utility's "All Messages" log stream when you launch it? For example, if you saw a message from `dyld` about a library not found, that would indicate it uses an old library that is no longer included in macOS.

Comment: 'Fraise' is no longer in development, which is unfortunate because it was a good text editor. I opened up the console and did a search for `dyld`, with 0 results, so it can't be that. I also took a look when trying to open the app, and the only results which seem mildly related are listed as `<private>` from the process `DuetHeuristic-BM` (`com.apple.duetactivityscheduler`) - these listings only appear when trying to open the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Choose “Show Package Contents” in the context menu.
2. run Contents/MacOS/Fraise

I assume that the error will be "Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.". It seems that Apple is no more supporting those old apps with "garbage collection with macOS 10.12.

Comment: Yeah, Garbage Collection is definitely the problem here. Happily, Fraise was open source, so I'm working on creating a new version using ARC instead. Thanks for your answer though!